# XML Parsing Error: no root element found in iis

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I am very new to web services. I have wrote a web service application. When I run it from visual studio, everything works fine and my local website comes up. But after I deployed it in IIS, I can't browse it from iis and i get the following error! I am confused about this error for a day! Can some one help me?
XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://localhost:99/WebService.asmx
Line Number 1, Column 1:

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when I deployed a project on my local new computer. By default, ASP.NET is installed but disabled in Windows.I had to enable it before my project run. See [Install IIS and ASP.NET Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules) for details.
Make sure that all the required modules are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but had ASP.NET modules installed. Apparently had to change .NET Framework Version from v2.0 to v4.0 and site was showing as it should. You need to go to IIS, Application Pools, double click the one that has older version of .NET and set the relevant one. Maybe this will be helpful for someone else.